# 'Unicode' vs. 'String' with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, sqlalchemy, python-2.x

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge concerning character encoding.

My question is: are there any inherent advantages/disadvantages to using the 'Unicode' type, rather than the 'String' type,  when storing data in PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy (or vice-versa)? If so, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I assume this is python2?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yessir. However, your asking that also makes me curious as to how the question, and answer, would differ w/python3.

Comment: python3 uses unicode for all string representations, while python2 doesn't. That causes problems for python2 programs that convert between byte strings and unicode strings, which Python3 programs can usually dodge. The python docs have a [section](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#tips-for-writing-unicode-aware-programs) that talks about this. [This](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html) is also a good read on the frustrations of unicode in python2. Despite the annoyance, it's probably best to work with unicode because it seems to be the future-proof direction.

Comment: I think the question is about sqlalchemy.Unicode column type vs sqlalchemy.String column type. Not regarding the standard python unicode/string types, of which a lot has been written already.

Answer (score 4):

In 99.99% of the cases go for Unicode and if possible use Python 3 as it would make your life easier.

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate on why?